# Thymeleaf - POST/PATCH method on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I trying to make a PATCH/POST method on checkboxes (**THYMELEAF**).

I think that I have to use javascript, but I don't know how (using **th:each** to display all the tasks).

```
<dl th:each="task, taskStat : ${tasks}" class="Bd P(10px)">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="return myFunction()" th:value="${task.id}" th:checked="${task.isDone()}"
               th:text="${task.getDescription} + ' |'"/>
        <small th:text="${task.getDeadline()}"></small>
        <small th:if="${task.getDeadline()} == null">(no deadline)</small>
        <button class="button" style="float: right">Edit</button>
    </label>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that

```
th:onclick="attentionAuthor([[${contentIndexDto.content.userId}]])"
```

use THYMELEAF `[[ ]]` to implement it

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, I did something wrong. 
But I found another solution: I used th:attr and onlick with javascript function.
Anyway thank you <3